# Laravel can't find bootstrap style

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, bootstrap-material-design

I'm trying to install bootstrap from https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design. But when I follow the instructions it won't work. I've put the 3 maps css,fonts and js in the public folder. This is my master.blade view :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> @yield('title') </title>
   <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Include roboto.css to use the Roboto web font, material.css to include the theme and ripples.css to style the ripple effect -->
    <link href="/css/roboto.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/ripples.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

@include('shared.navbar')

@yield('content')

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="/js/ripples.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/material.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // This command is used to initialize some elements and make them work properly
        $.material.init();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes my url to public folder is currently http://localhost/laravel/public/

Comment: First thing to check is your browser console to see if any files are linked wrong.

Comment: try to put the link with http `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: @Shehary That doesn't work.

Comment: @patricksweeney what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Your browser console will tell you of any errors - like if you linked some CSS or JS wrong. It's typically the F12 key.

Comment: The console is telling me: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost/laravel/public/public/css/material.min.css

Comment: That means it can't find that file. Debug why that is. A small hint: you're telling it to look in the wrong directory.

Comment: If I put it in public/public it also won't work.

Comment: In Laravel, unless you've changed it the web root is `public` - thus, assets in the `public` directory should not have `public` in the path. For example, my CSS files are in `public/assets/css`. The URL to load those assets is `http://localhost/assets/css/something.css`.

Comment: `<link href="<?= asset('css/roboto.min.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following one :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

let me know if it works... ref: [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)